# Get nested tags using Mootools

Tags: javascript, mootools

I have HTMl structure as follows

```
<div class="comments_options" id="comment_2">
    <span>2 comments</span>
</div>
```

In Mootools we can collect the comment count based on style class as follows,

```
var commentCount = $$('.comments_options span')[0];
```

How can we do the same according to id attribute

Thanks

Comment: ID should always be something unique, so I don't understand tour question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getElement`

```
document.id("comment_2").getElement("span");
```

or `getFirst`

```
document.id("comment_2").getFirst("span");
```